# Can't add Visual Studio Team Services Plugin in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/microsoft/alm/plugin/services/AsyncService
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.registerComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:412)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:96)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:458)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:450)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:197)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:52)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:366)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.alm.plugin.services.AsyncService PluginClassLoader[com.microsoft.vso.idea, 1.116.1]
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:64)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 23 more
```

I want to add the plugin using one of the both flow. Please help.

I want to add Visual Studio Team Service Plugin in Android studio. 
Here I have 2 issues -

1. If I try install this plugin from Setting>Plugin>Browse Repo> then error message is "Download failed " with can't Read message.
2. If I download Plugin from https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7981-visual-studio-team-services and add jar file using Setting > Plugins > Install plugin from disk. Plugin is added. But If i restart the Android studio than getting this error message -
   Plugin 'com.microsoft.vso.idea' failed to initialize and will be disabled.  Please restart Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

In the second case, you probably downloaded `plugin.idea-1.xxx.zip` file, extracted the content, clicked `Install plugin from disk` in android studio and then you picked a `.jar` file from the extracted content called `com.microsoft.alm.plugin.idea-1.xxx.jar` and that is what caused the error you posted. What you should have done is picking the `.zip` file itself without unzipping it, this will cause no errors and the plugin will work correctly.
I hope this is helpful.